# Yii model () method findBySQL ( 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM ee_car_types;');

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I cant figure it out how to get last entered entry by database I'm trying to find it by largest ID, but it seems not work.

```
EeCarTypes::model()->findBySql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM ee_car_types');
```

...doesnt work. But if I write this statement in phpmyadmin  `SELECT MAX(id) FROM ee_car_types;` it finds it. Could you please tell me where Im wrong?

Comment: Your quotes are off in your example, not sure if that's only for this question or if that's from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way `$criteria->order = 'id DESC';`:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';

/* @var $firstEntry EeCarTypes */
$firstEntry = EeCarTypes::model()->find($criteria);
```

Also this solution will work for you:

```
$firstEntry = EeCarTypes::model()->find(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
```

Comment: This project is in Yii, and I recently just started working as web developer and everthing is new to me. Thank you man.

Comment: Does it work for you? Please mark the answer. And welcome to Yii ;)

Comment: @Townsheriff, can you mark this answer as right? Give it the tick?